# Azure App Service Plan - What does minutes/day mean?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have ASMX webservice with 1 MSSQL Database and a Single Table.
I have currently deployed it to Azure in the ***App Service***
I have upgraded from Free Trial to Pay Per Use Plan.
I'm really confused with the ***App Service Plan***

[image]

The ASMX Service is called by a Desktop application and it only has a few methods,just to fetch and return data from database.At max 100 users will be using it and may be a maximum of 1000 method calls may be made.

What does 60 minutes/day mean? The webservice can function for only 60 minutes?
I'm really confused.Please advice

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Think of the minutes listed similar to a consumption plan on Azure Functions.  When your website is responding to requests, it active and your "on the clock."  When the site has been idle for a while, it will effectively go to sleep and you are "off the clock."  Free and shared tiers are not "Always On".  If your compute minute usage exceeds the quota (60 or 240 minutes), then Azure will return a 403 message to the browser and your site is unavailable until the quota resets for the next day.  Free and Shared plans are really not designed for production.  If you think you can squeeze your 1000 method calls into those time limits, great...it may be a cheaper solution.  But you should expect the possibility of a 403 being returned and your request not being fulfilled.  If your desktop app is important and really needs this service, you are probably better off paying for Basic (B1).

Comment: This is a great answer and I also finally understand what they mean by minutes/day. However, if I choose the Basic (B1) plan do I pay the set monthly fee or I pay for what I use?

Comment: @LyubomirIvanovValchev, once you are at the Basic level, you just pay a flat rate for the resources at that level.  You're not paying for usage time. But you are still paying for fixed resources; so even though it is flat rate, if your site has high usage, it may be slow (not enough compute/memory, etc).