# Is Azure D1 App Service plan OK for small production asp.net core website

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a small website in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.
Number of visitor will be low (max 1000 per day, but probably no more than 500).

My questions:

1. Is it OK to deploy the website to the D1 Shared plan (which I'm using for testing now)?
2. If I understand correctly it will cost me around €9/month. Is this right?
3. What does it mean "240 CPU minutes / day"? Is the website offline in sleep mode when not in use?
4. What will happen if I go above 240 CPU minutes / day (is it possible?)?
5. I like the Azure panel and configuration screen but is there a better alternative (not a VPS) to host a small website like above?

Comment: I have found good answer about point 3 & 4 here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481074/azure-app-service-plan-what-does-minutes-day-mean so I just need some help with 1,2 & 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.As you may know, the D1 Shared plan is for `test / develop`, not for `production`. And it only supports `240 CPU minutes / day`, so 500 or 1000 visit per day may exceed this limitation and cause some problems. It's not ok.

2.It will cost you about **€8.003/month**. Here is a screenshot from the pricing page:

[image]

5.Another solution without considering other cloud service(like google cloud etc.), if you don't mind re-writing you site, you can consider using [azure static web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) which is more cheaper(the limitation is that it can only host very simple site).